# Server listenning at port with endpoint

Tags: java, sockets, server, port

I have created a server using sockets in Java and it is ready to receive HTTP requests and emit HTTP response. 
The server is on a port of my PC, but I want to listen only into an "endpoint", I mean, I want to mount the server i.e. on `localhost:60802/json`. 
Is this possible? My code is here:

```
            PORT = Integer.parseInt(portSelection.getText());
            th =  new Thread(new Runnable() {

                //String file;
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try{
                        server = new ServerSocket(PORT);

                        while(open) {
                            //Accept connections
                            connection = server.accept();

                            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())); 

                            try {
                                String line="";

                                while ((line=in.readLine())!= null && !line.equals("")){log.append(line);}                                                              
                                in.close();
                            }catch (Exception e1) {
                            }
                        }
                    }catch (EOFException e1 ) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }catch (BindException e1) {
                        log.setText("Error. Port "+PORT+" already in use.");
                        open=false;
                    }catch (SocketException e1) {

                    }catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            th.start();
```

I have omitted some parts, so maybe you detect an error, but code works perfect at this time.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to mount the server i.e. on localhost:60802/json. Is this possible?

You can listen on localhost port 60802.   That will accept all connnections on that IP / port.  Beyond that your server code needs to:

1. read the HTTP request
2. decode the first line to extract the request URL
3. decide if the URL's path matches the path of your "endpoint" URL; i.e. "/json/*"

   - if yes, then continue
   - if no, then send an appropriate HTTP error response; e.g. 404 Not Found

(Alternatively, you could put your server code behind a reverse proxy that deals with that stuff and rewrites the request URL as well.  But that may defeat your purpose in doing this using sockets ....)

---

But to be frank, writing an HTTP server using sockets is a bad idea.  A lot of work, and you are likely to end up with a service that doesn't implement the HTTP specs correctly.  You are better of using an existing web server / container (e.g. Tomcat, Jetty, Glassfish, SpringBoot, etcetera) or the Apache HttpComponents library.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

Server is bound to particular TCP port (and interface if provided).
If you want to give response only at /json path just make a conditional statement that is checking URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you use spring boot to mount your server and the web-service it will be much easier than to re-code everything.

Please have a look at:
[Building a RESTful Web Service with Spring Boot Actuator](https://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service/)

Then you can develop an application for every group of web-services and for every group of web-services you can specify a particular port under the `application.properties` file:

```
server.port= 60802
```